# How to loop through an external file using an array and strtok PHP

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, associative-array, infinite-loop

I am getting an infinite loop. I believe that I am reading in the same line of input multiple times instead of going to the next line. From what I can come up with I need another piece of code just above the end of the while loop that moves to the next piece. I need to do this using strtok, my question is how?

UPDATE: MUST USE A FOREACH LOOP, NO EXPLODE/IMPLODE.

the "include file is bbs_2013invent.php and reads:

```
<?php
$data =
"Sunscreen_SPF-55 BB-ss1 S 9.98 83 828.34 4.99 NA
Sunscreen_SPF-7000 BB-ss2 S 29.98 9 269.82 19 NA
SunHat-F BB-sh3 S 33.79 41 1385.39 25.5 NA
SunHat-M BB-sh8 S 41.79 18 752.22 29.5 NA
Sandals BB-sd4 S 19.38 32 620.16 4.75 NA
Towel-Large BB-tl S 45 57 2565.00 29.99 NA
Towel-Indiv BB-ts S 11.75 133 1562.75 5.9 NA
Beach_Chair BB-bc2 S 67.5 19 1282.50 47.5 NA
Umbrella BB-umb R 129 18 2322 398 0.4
Surfboard BB-surf2 R 135 27 3645 735 0.2
JetSki BB-jsk7 R 160.25 38 6089.50 18795.00 0.4
Outlaw20_Powerboat BB-pb20 R 298 11 3278 67850.00 0.3";
?>
```

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
<?PHP    
//Imports a file
include 'bbs_2013invent.php';
//variable
$delimiters = "\n";

//Declare and fill array
$product = ['name'    => rtrim(strtok($data, $delimiters)),
       'serial'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'status'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'price'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'units'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'revenue'  => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'cost'     => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'factor'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       ];

//Column headers
printf("PRODUCT  \tSERIAL#  \tPRICE/RENTALCHG   \tUNITS/DAYS    \tREVENUE   \tORIGCOST  \tNOTES");
//while loop
while(['name'])
{
//Calculates the total days rented and revenue respectively
$totalDays += $units;
$totalRevenue += $revenue;
if ($key == 'status' && $value = S && "units" <800)
{
  printf("\t L");
}
if ($key == 'status' && $value = R && "units" <20)
{
  printf("\t LR");
}

//foreach loop
foreach($product as $key => $value)
{
printf($key, $value);
}

} //end of while loop
//displays the total number of days items have been rented
printf($totalDays);
//displays the total revenue of all products combined
printf($totalRevenue);
?>
```

Comment: I'm sure there's an easier way.  What is your desired output?  `while(['name'])` will always be true.

Comment: EX:
PRODUCT    SERIAL    PRICE    UNITS    REVENUE    ORIGCOST    NOTES
sunscreen  BB-ss1    9.98     83       828.34     4.99        NA
chair      BB-ch2  .....

Comment: The reply removes all formatting, but basically Column headers with the product data beneath

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, I've just edited a bit your code just to have a working sample, your code had various problems here and there. I think this could help you to follow your way by yourself.

```
$data =
"Sunscreen_SPF-55 BB-ss1 S 9.98 83 828.34 4.99 NA
Sunscreen_SPF-7000 BB-ss2 S 29.98 9 269.82 19 NA
SunHat-F BB-sh3 S 33.79 41 1385.39 25.5 NA
SunHat-M BB-sh8 S 41.79 18 752.22 29.5 NA
Sandals BB-sd4 S 19.38 32 620.16 4.75 NA
Towel-Large BB-tl S 45 57 2565.00 29.99 NA
Towel-Indiv BB-ts S 11.75 133 1562.75 5.9 NA
Beach_Chair BB-bc2 S 67.5 19 1282.50 47.5 NA
Umbrella BB-umb R 129 18 2322 398 0.4
Surfboard BB-surf2 R 135 27 3645 735 0.2
JetSki BB-jsk7 R 160.25 38 6089.50 18795.00 0.4
Outlaw20_Powerboat BB-pb20 R 298 11 3278 67850.00 0.3";

$delimiters = " ";
$totalDays = 0;
$totalRevenue = 0;

printf("PRODUCT  \tSERIAL#  \tPRICE/RENTALCHG   \tUNITS/DAYS    \tREVENUE   \tORIGCOST  \tNOTES <br>");

$data = explode("\n", $data);

while($data)
{
    $line = array_shift($data); 

    $product = ['name'    => rtrim(strtok($line, $delimiters)),
       'serial'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'status'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'price'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'units'    => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'revenue'  => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'cost'     => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
       'factor'   => rtrim(strtok($delimiters)),
    ];

    $totalDays += $product['units'];
    $totalRevenue += $product['revenue'];

    if ($product['status'] == "S" && $product["units"] < 800)
    {
        printf("\t [L] ");
    }
    if ($product['status'] == "R" && $product["units"] < 20)
    {
        printf("\t [LR] ");
    }

    printf(implode("\t", $product) . "<br>");
}

printf("<br>totalDays: ".$totalDays);
printf("<br>totalRevenue: ".$totalRevenue);
```

Comment: Just to make sure, does this take into account that I have to import the $data variable from bbs_2013invent.php ?

Comment: Include does this, copy the content of the called file and insert it into the scope. So, the same as having a variable there, in your case. however, You can give it a try. Take off the initial `$data` variable and insert your include..include 'bbs_2013invent.php';. Then let us know if it works

Comment: It came close and left me with just a few errors I was able to work out, however, the professor doesn't want the use of explode/implode.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
//variable
$delimiters = "\n";

$product = rtrim(strtok($data, $delimiters));

//Column headers
printf("PRODUCT  \tSERIAL#  \tPRICE/RENTALCHG   \tUNITS/DAYS    \tREVENUE   \tORIGCOST  \tNOTES");

//while loop
while($product)
{
    printf($product);

    list($name, $serial, $status, $price, $units, $revenue, $cost, $factor) = explode(' ', $product);

    //Calculates the total days rented and revenue respectively
    $totalDays += $units;
    $totalRevenue += $revenue;
    if ($status == 'S' && $units <800)
    {
      printf("\t L");
    }
    if ($status == 'R' && $units <20)
    {
      printf("\t LR");
    }

    $product = rtrim(strtok($delimiters));
} //end of while loop

//displays the total number of days items have been rented
printf($totalDays);
//displays the total revenue of all products combined
printf($totalRevenue);
```